# What is this widget called?

Tags: user-interface, qt, widget

There is a rotary control I have seen that is like the edge-on view of a knurled volume control wheel on an old Walkman.
Without knowing what it's called I can't search for it - I'm pretty sure that the app was based on Qt.

Edit - having tried it on a couple of people younger than me it seems that the iPod generation don't know volume knobs!  Looks like I need to use up-down arrows instead (it's not actually a volume it's a rotate view)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of this widget? And are you sure it is standard widget, it could be custom-made control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"edge of a knurled volume control" sounds like the [QwtWheel](http://www.digitalfanatics.org/e8johan/projects/widgets/qwtwheel.html) to me.

Comment: Thanks - that explains why a search of the Qt widgets didn't find it. I thought Qwt was only graph plotting.

It doesn't look exactly like the example I say but it is close enough for what I need.

Comment: You could always derive it to get the look-and-feel you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

Is it QwtKnob?

Check the gallery here http://www.digitalfanatics.org/e8johan/projects/widgets/

Answer (score -1):

sounds like volume control